# What does .upgradeElements do?

Tags: javascript, material-design

I happened to come across in a Javascript File using the Material DesignLite Library, I didn't quite understand what does .upgradeElements do?`componentHandler.upgradeElements(postElement.getElementsByClassName('mdl-textfield')[0]);`